# Are file systems like SFS and UFS still used today?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, ufs

I have read the Wikipedia pages for both these file systems:

- [SFS (Smart File System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_File_System)
- [UFS (Unix File System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System)

but I couldn't find a real answer. For example, for SFS the common Operating Systems that use it are listed as AmigaOS, AROS and MorphOS. But I haven't heard of those being used today. Unix-based OSes like FreeBSD also use ext2/3 by default — or at least that is what I have read, might be wrong.

Are these file systems still used?

The reason I am asking is that, for example, the SFS uses a technique to avoid fragmentation when appending data to a file. It removes the allocated data completly (if the extend has no room when after the initial data) and places it in a new place where enough sequential data is free. The SFS is the only file system I have found that does this. Is that correct?

Comment: There are two questions here: "Are Filesystems like SFS and UFS still used today?" and "The SFS is the only filesystem I have found that does this. Is that correct?". You could reword your question to "What anti-fragmentation techniques are used in modern filesystems" or something similar, but I'm afraid it would be too broad for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. The second question is not that important. I am ok if it won't be answered.

Answer (score 3):

FreeBSD, NetBSD, and OpenBSD all use UFS by default.  As jillagre mentions in the comments, Solaris also uses it but not by default. ext* file systems are mostly a Linux thing, there's not a lot of support outside of Linux for them.
And, to my knowledge, MorphOS is an actively developed OS still, so surely there are some users of it.

Comment: You  can add Solaris to the list of OSes using UFS although ZFS is now the default file system.